# Mysql upgrade help on windows environment?

Tags: mysql

I have installed mysql community server 5.7.17 log, i checked on mysql website and found out that there was 5.7.18 released.

Is it ok if i upgrade to latest general version?

Can you please help me in details how to do step by step , All i got articles for linux environment . Need help in windows environment?

Answer (score 0):

It is almost always safe to upgrade to new minor release (5.7.x to 5.7.y); MySQL very rarely has an regressions.

By the same token, there are very rarely any benefits in jumping on a minor update, especially the next (.17 to .18); any bugs that are fixed or features that are added probably are in some obscure area that won't affect you.

A major upgrade (5.6.x to 5.7.y or 5.7.y to 8.0.z -- the numbering is not consistent) should eventually be done, but with more caution.  There are usually incompatibilities, etc, that might bite you.

Each new release has a web page called "changelog".  It is MySQL's warning of what might affect you.  But mostly it is a cure for insomnia.

Answer (score -1):

A google search resulted in this : 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/windows-upgrading.html

Follow it step by step and you won't mess up.

Comment: Thanks @Prabhat G. I know we have documentation but I need proper steps by steps who did it.